# NimbusLookAndFeel and serialization

Tags: java, swing, jtable, nimbus

Hi I want to filter JTable in NimbusLookAndFeel because when I save my program the JTable change I want show all of thing into the NimbusLookAndFeel but I use the default JTable in my class thank you!

[image]

You see in before and after saving. I want stop NimbusLookAndFeel JTable.

[image]

Comment: Probably you can post your code here? Without code we cannot help you.

Comment: Just a wild guess but I'd say it's the same problem you got in your other question. You're most likely calling setLookAndFeel() in the totally wrong place.